# How to make a time dependent distribution in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL Table in which I keep project information coming from primavera.
Suppose that i have columns for Start Date,End Date,Duration, and Total Qty as shown below .
How can i distribute Total Qty over **Months** using these information. What kind of additional columns, sql queries i need in order to get correct monthly distribution?

Thanks in Advance.

Columns in order:

```
itemname,quantity,startdate,duration,enddate

item1 -- 108 -- 2013-03-25 -- 720 -- 2013-07-26 
item2 -- 640 -- 2013-03-25 -- 720 -- 2013-07-26
  .
  .
```

Comment: How is the Month to be calculated from the StartDate and EndDate if they are not in the same month?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I m using MSSQL 2008. For example, i can find daily qty by dividing qty/duration. But i dont know how to distribute those monthly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to break the records apart by month.  Here is an example of how to do it:

```
with months as (
     select 1 as mon union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
     select 4 as mon union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
     select 7 as mon union all select 8 union all select 9 union all
     select 10 as mon union all select 11 union all select 12
    )
select item, m.mon, quantity / nummonths
from (select t.*, (month(enddate) - month(startdate) + 1) as nummonths
      from t
     ) t join
     months m
     on month(t.startDate) <= m.mon and
        months(t.endDate) >= m.mon;
```

This works because all the months are within the same year -- as in your example.  You are quite vague on how the split should be calculated.  So, I assumed that every month from the start to the end gets an equal amount.

Comment: Thank you, somehow i have managed with that distribution with help   of a calendar table which is crossjoined.